# Android - как заставить приложение реагировать на кнопки гарнитуры/клавиатуры?

Tags: headset, android, java, клавиатура

Пишу плеер. Мне нужно как-то заставить приложение реагровать на кнопки гарнитуры/клавиатуры (главное, чтоб работало в фоне).
В каком направлении копать?

Единственное, что знаю, так это коды клавиш *клавиатуры* (не путать с гарнитурой), которые должно принимать приложение:

```
88 - Предыдущая дорожка
85 - Приостановить/Воспроизвести
87 - Следующая дорожка
```

Comment: Вроде бы как оно... https://stackoverflow.com/a/17983446/1659629

Comment: Спасибо! И ещё такой вопрос: как мне добавить receiver в манифест, если у него нет выделенного класса?
То есть у меня вот так:

    public class A extends Activity {
        class B extends BroadcastReceiver {...}
    }

Comment: вот это я не скажу... можете попробовать сделать    
**public** class B extends

Comment: Не помогло

Comment: @SuperCreeper инициализируете `BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()` и регестрируете в `onResume`

Comment: А через манифест можно?

Comment: через манифест отдельным, внешним классом

Comment: Нашёл способ добавления ресивера в классе в манифест!
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".Класс$Ресивер > ... </receiver>